# React-navigation navigate at startup

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation in my app; I have a Navigator like this:

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

<RootStack.Navigator>
  <RootStack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
  <RootStack.Screen name="B" component={B} />
  <RootStack.Screen name="C" component={C} />
</RootStack.Navigator>
```

Now when the application starts `Main` will render; I am fetching some data with a redux action and based on that data it can be that I have to redirect the user to `C`

so in `Main` component I am simply doing

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (shouldRedirect)
    console.log('here')
    navigation.navigate('C')
  }
}, [shouldRedirect])
```

Well at this point I can see the log in the console but the navigation it's not happening;
I guess it's due to the fact that something is not ready yet, because just wrapping the `navigate` in a timeout like the following, makes it work as expected:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (shouldRedirect) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigation.navigate('C')
    }, 1)
  }
}, [shouldRedirect])
```

anyway this looks like an ugly workaround; I'd like to understand how to implement this properly...

Answer (score 1):

You should also add `navigation` to your dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (shouldRedirect)
    console.log('here')
    navigation.navigate('C')
  }
}, [navigation, shouldRedirect])
```

Comment: I accepted the answer initially since when I tried it seemed it was working, but actually it was just a case... I tried on a fresh new app to test it without any kind of other effects and adding this dependency has no effect for me

Comment: I'm sorry to see it is not working. Can you tell me which version of @react-navigation/stack you are using? I created a basic example based on yours, it immediately navigate to C successfully. And what happens if you just call your navigation.navigate in an empty dependency [] and without shouldRedirect condition statement (i mean a pure componentDidmount)?

Comment: And can you also try to use initialRouteName like this : <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Main">